# length of each cell in python and keep only characters till 4

Tags: python

I have a column which is consists of nearly 1000+ records

1. I want to know the each cell length
2. after that i want to keep only 4 characters in every record

Eg:

| Column Name |
| --- |
| Data |
| Sample Data |
| Sample |
| BigDAta |

Here I've Column Name as my Column Name. Remaining 4 are my data. I need to calculate each cell length (how many characters including space Eg: Data is consisting of 4). I want to keep only characters till 4.

Output should be:

| Column Name |
| --- |
| Data |
| Samp |
| Samp |
| BigD |

Can anyone please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data structure is your data stored in? Is it a `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: share some code

Answer (score 0):

assuming it's a pandas DF, try:

```
df['l'] = df['Column Name'].str.len()
df['first_four'] = df['Column Name'].str[:4]
```

| Column Name | l | first_four |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data | 4 | Data |
| Sample Data | 11 | Samp |
| Sample | 6 | Samp |
| BigDAta | 7 | BigD |

Answer (score 0):

Read your tables into pandas and then slice each value as a string:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mytable.csv')
for i in df.columns:
    df[i] = df[i].str[0:4]
```